# esp8266 mDNS was working, but has now stopped

Tags: network-programming, arduino-esp8266, mdns

I got the mDNS responder working on my ESP8266.  It's been working for weeks, I can ping, nslookup and go to the web page.  I'm using win10 and Android phone, both worked great.
Then it appeared to stop responding to the local name (IP still works fine).
The weird part is, when I turned on the debug messages on the console, mDNS still appears to be working, but the clients still can't find it.

Below are debug logs, but from what I can tell it should be working.  Any mDNS experts out there that can see what is going wrong?
Thanks!

Here it is starting up:

```
Hard resetting via RTS pin...
=============================================== [SUCCESS] Took 37.10 seconds ===============================================
--- Available filters and text transformations: colorize, debug, default, direct, esp8266_exception_decoder, hexlify, log2file, nocontrol, printable, send_on_enter, time
--- More details at ...
--- Miniterm on COM3  115200,8,N,1 ---
--- Quit: Ctrl+C | Menu: Ctrl+T | Help: Ctrl+T followed by Ctrl+H ---

-- BME280 connected on address 0x76 --

-- Configuring GPIO --
isMode: 2
Connecting to WiFi
.
.
.
.
192.168.86.71
[MDNSResponder] _allocUDPContext
MDNS started
[MDNSResponder] addService: Succeeded to add 'therm1.http.TCP'!

ezTime debug level set to INFO
Syncing NTP
Waiting for time sync
Querying time.google.com ... success (round trip 51 ms)
Received time: Thursday, 10-Mar-22 13:52:34.870 UTC
Time is in sync
our Timezone: America/Chicago
Timezone lookup for: America/Chicago ... [MDNSResponder] _callProcess (8098, triggered by: 192.168.86.163)
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage (Time: 8098 ms, heap: 43184 bytes, from 192.168.86.163(5353), to 224.0.0.251(5353))
[MDNSResponder] _readRRQuestion
[MDNSResponder] _readRRQuestion _%9E5E7C8F47989526C9BCD95D24084F6F0B27C5ED._sub._googlecast._tcp.local Type:0x000C Class:0x0001 Multicast
[MDNSResponder] _readRRQuestion
[MDNSResponder] _readRRQuestion _googlecast._tcp.local Type:0x000C Class:0x0001 Multicast
[MDNSResponder] _parseQuery: No reply needed
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage: Done (Succeeded after 34 ms, ate 0 bytes, remaining 43184)

[MDNSResponder] _callProcess (8141, triggered by: 192.168.86.163)
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage (Time: 8146 ms, heap: 42896 bytes, from 192.168.86.21(5353), to 224.0.0.251(5353))
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage: Done (Succeeded after 10 ms, ate 0 bytes, remaining 42896)

[MDNSResponder] _callProcess (8164, triggered by: 192.168.86.21)
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage (Time: 8169 ms, heap: 42768 bytes, from 192.168.86.112(5353), to 224.0.0.251(5353))
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage: Done (Succeeded after 10 ms, ate 0 bytes, remaining 42768)

[MDNSResponder] _callProcess (8187, triggered by: 192.168.86.112)
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage (Time: 8193 ms, heap: 42760 bytes, from 192.168.86.127(5353), to 224.0.0.251(5353))
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage: Done (Succeeded after 9 ms, ate 0 bytes, remaining 42760)

[MDNSResponder] _callProcess (8211, triggered by: 192.168.86.127)
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage (Time: 8216 ms, heap: 42784 bytes, from 192.168.86.127(5353), to 224.0.0.251(5353))
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage: Done (Succeeded after 10 ms, ate 0 bytes, remaining 42784)

(round-trip 486 ms)  success.
  Olson: America/Chicago
  Posix: CST6CDT,M3.2.0,M11.1.0
Central Time:     Thursday, 10-Mar-2022 07:52:35 CST
[MDNSResponder] _updateProbeStatus: Starting host probing...
[MDNSResponder] _sendHostProbe (therm1, 8435)
[MDNSResponder] _sendMDNSMessage_Multicast: Will send to '224.0.0.251'.
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage: ID:0 QR:0 OP:0 AA:0 TC:0 RD:0 RA:0 R:0 QD:1 AN:0 NS:1 AR:0
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSQuestion
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_A (192.168.86.71)
[MDNSResponder] _updateProbeStatus: Did sent host probe

[MDNSResponder] _sendServiceProbe (therm1.http.TCP, 8502)
[MDNSResponder] _sendMDNSMessage_Multicast: Will send to '224.0.0.251'.
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage: ID:0 QR:0 OP:0 AA:0 TC:0 RD:0 RA:0 R:0 QD:1 AN:0 NS:2 AR:2
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSQuestion
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_PTR_NAME
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_SRV
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_TXT
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_A (192.168.86.71)
[MDNSResponder] _updateProbeStatus: Did sent service probe (1)

[MDNSResponder] _sendHostProbe (therm1, 8708)
[MDNSResponder] _sendMDNSMessage_Multicast: Will send to '224.0.0.251'.
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage: ID:0 QR:0 OP:0 AA:0 TC:0 RD:0 RA:0 R:0 QD:1 AN:0 NS:1 AR:0
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSQuestion
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_A (192.168.86.71)
[MDNSResponder] _updateProbeStatus: Did sent host probe

[MDNSResponder] _sendServiceProbe (therm1.http.TCP, 8787)
[MDNSResponder] _sendMDNSMessage_Multicast: Will send to '224.0.0.251'.
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage: ID:0 QR:0 OP:0 AA:0 TC:0 RD:0 RA:0 R:0 QD:1 AN:0 NS:2 AR:2
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSQuestion
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_PTR_NAME
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_SRV
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_TXT
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_A (192.168.86.71)
[MDNSResponder] _updateProbeStatus: Did sent service probe (2)

[MDNSResponder] _sendHostProbe (therm1, 8981)
[MDNSResponder] _sendMDNSMessage_Multicast: Will send to '224.0.0.251'.
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage: ID:0 QR:0 OP:0 AA:0 TC:0 RD:0 RA:0 R:0 QD:1 AN:0 NS:1 AR:0
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSQuestion
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_A (192.168.86.71)
[MDNSResponder] _updateProbeStatus: Did sent host probe

[MDNSResponder] _sendServiceProbe (therm1.http.TCP, 9071)
[MDNSResponder] _sendMDNSMessage_Multicast: Will send to '224.0.0.251'.
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage: ID:0 QR:0 OP:0 AA:0 TC:0 RD:0 RA:0 R:0 QD:1 AN:0 NS:2 AR:2
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSQuestion
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_PTR_NAME
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_SRV
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_TXT
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_A (192.168.86.71)
[MDNSResponder] _updateProbeStatus: Did sent service probe (3)

[MDNSResponder] _updateProbeStatus: Done host probing.
[MDNSResponder] _updateProbeStatus: Prepared host announcing.

[MDNSResponder] _updateProbeStatus: Done service probing therm1.http.TCP

[MDNSResponder] _updateProbeStatus: Prepared service announcing.

[MDNSResponder] _announce: Announcing host therm1 (content 0x3)
[MDNSResponder] _sendMDNSMessage_Multicast: Will send to '224.0.0.251'.
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage: ID:0 QR:1 OP:0 AA:1 TC:0 RD:0 RA:0 R:0 QD:0 AN:2 NS:0 AR:0
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_A (192.168.86.71)
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_PTR_IP4 (192.168.86.71)
[MDNSResponder] _updateProbeStatus: Announcing host (1).

[MDNSResponder] _announceService: Announcing service therm1.http.TCP (content 0xF0)
[MDNSResponder] _sendMDNSMessage_Multicast: Will send to '224.0.0.251'.
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage: ID:0 QR:1 OP:0 AA:1 TC:0 RD:0 RA:0 R:0 QD:0 AN:4 NS:0 AR:1
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_PTR_TYPE
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_PTR_NAME
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_SRV
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_TXT
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_A (192.168.86.71)
[MDNSResponder] _updateProbeStatus: Announcing service therm1.http.TCP (1)

[MDNSResponder] _announce: Announcing host therm1 (content 0x3)
[MDNSResponder] _sendMDNSMessage_Multicast: Will send to '224.0.0.251'.
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage: ID:0 QR:1 OP:0 AA:1 TC:0 RD:0 RA:0 R:0 QD:0 AN:2 NS:0 AR:0
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_A (192.168.86.71)
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_PTR_IP4 (192.168.86.71)
[MDNSResponder] _updateProbeStatus: Announcing host (2).

[MDNSResponder] _announceService: Announcing service therm1.http.TCP (content 0xF0)
[MDNSResponder] _sendMDNSMessage_Multicast: Will send to '224.0.0.251'.
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage: ID:0 QR:1 OP:0 AA:1 TC:0 RD:0 RA:0 R:0 QD:0 AN:4 NS:0 AR:1
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_PTR_TYPE
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_PTR_NAME
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_SRV
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_TXT
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_A (192.168.86.71)
[MDNSResponder] _updateProbeStatus: Announcing service therm1.http.TCP (2)

[MDNSResponder] _announce: Announcing host therm1 (content 0x3)
[MDNSResponder] _sendMDNSMessage_Multicast: Will send to '224.0.0.251'.
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage: ID:0 QR:1 OP:0 AA:1 TC:0 RD:0 RA:0 R:0 QD:0 AN:2 NS:0 AR:0
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_A (192.168.86.71)
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_PTR_IP4 (192.168.86.71)
[MDNSResponder] _updateProbeStatus: Announcing host (3).

[MDNSResponder] _announceService: Announcing service therm1.http.TCP (content 0xF0)
[MDNSResponder] _sendMDNSMessage_Multicast: Will send to '224.0.0.251'.
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage: ID:0 QR:1 OP:0 AA:1 TC:0 RD:0 RA:0 R:0 QD:0 AN:4 NS:0 AR:1
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_PTR_TYPE
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_PTR_NAME
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_SRV
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_TXT
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_A (192.168.86.71)
[MDNSResponder] _updateProbeStatus: Announcing service therm1.http.TCP (3)

[MDNSResponder] _announce: Announcing host therm1 (content 0x3)
[MDNSResponder] _sendMDNSMessage_Multicast: Will send to '224.0.0.251'.
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage: ID:0 QR:1 OP:0 AA:1 TC:0 RD:0 RA:0 R:0 QD:0 AN:2 NS:0 AR:0
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_A (192.168.86.71)
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_PTR_IP4 (192.168.86.71)
[MDNSResponder] _updateProbeStatus: Announcing host (4).

[MDNSResponder] _announceService: Announcing service therm1.http.TCP (content 0xF0)
[MDNSResponder] _sendMDNSMessage_Multicast: Will send to '224.0.0.251'.
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage: ID:0 QR:1 OP:0 AA:1 TC:0 RD:0 RA:0 R:0 QD:0 AN:4 NS:0 AR:1
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_PTR_TYPE
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_PTR_NAME
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_SRV
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_TXT
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_A (192.168.86.71)
[MDNSResponder] _updateProbeStatus: Announcing service therm1.http.TCP (4)

[MDNSResponder] _announce: Announcing host therm1 (content 0x3)
[MDNSResponder] _sendMDNSMessage_Multicast: Will send to '224.0.0.251'.
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage: ID:0 QR:1 OP:0 AA:1 TC:0 RD:0 RA:0 R:0 QD:0 AN:2 NS:0 AR:0
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_A (192.168.86.71)
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_PTR_IP4 (192.168.86.71)
[MDNSResponder] _updateProbeStatus: Announcing host (5).

[MDNSResponder] _announceService: Announcing service therm1.http.TCP (content 0xF0)
[MDNSResponder] _sendMDNSMessage_Multicast: Will send to '224.0.0.251'.
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage: ID:0 QR:1 OP:0 AA:1 TC:0 RD:0 RA:0 R:0 QD:0 AN:4 NS:0 AR:1
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_PTR_TYPE
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_PTR_NAME
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_SRV
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_TXT
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_A (192.168.86.71)
[MDNSResponder] _updateProbeStatus: Announcing service therm1.http.TCP (5)

[MDNSResponder] _announce: Announcing host therm1 (content 0x3)
[MDNSResponder] _sendMDNSMessage_Multicast: Will send to '224.0.0.251'.
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage: ID:0 QR:1 OP:0 AA:1 TC:0 RD:0 RA:0 R:0 QD:0 AN:2 NS:0 AR:0
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_A (192.168.86.71)
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_PTR_IP4 (192.168.86.71)
[MDNSResponder] _updateProbeStatus: Announcing host (6).

[MDNSResponder] _announceService: Announcing service therm1.http.TCP (content 0xF0)
[MDNSResponder] _sendMDNSMessage_Multicast: Will send to '224.0.0.251'.
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage: ID:0 QR:1 OP:0 AA:1 TC:0 RD:0 RA:0 R:0 QD:0 AN:4 NS:0 AR:1
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_PTR_TYPE
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_PTR_NAME
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_SRV
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_TXT
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_A (192.168.86.71)
[MDNSResponder] _updateProbeStatus: Announcing service therm1.http.TCP (6)

[MDNSResponder] _callProcess (16147, triggered by: 192.168.86.127)
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage (Time: 16148 ms, heap: 42000 bytes, from 192.168.86.165(5353), to 224.0.0.251(5353))
[MDNSResponder] _readRRQuestion
[MDNSResponder] _readRRQuestion _googlecast._tcp.local Type:0x000C Class:0x0001 Multicast
[MDNSResponder] _readRRQuestion
[MDNSResponder] _readRRQuestion _233637DE._sub._googlecast._tcp.local Type:0x000C Class:0x0001 Multicast
[MDNSResponder] _parseQuery: No reply needed
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage: Done (Succeeded after 31 ms, ate 0 bytes, remaining 42000)

[MDNSResponder] _callProcess (16187, triggered by: 192.168.86.165)
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage (Time: 16192 ms, heap: 41704 bytes, from 192.168.86.21(5353), to 224.0.0.251(5353))
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage: Done (Succeeded after 10 ms, ate 0 bytes, remaining 41704)

[MDNSResponder] _callProcess (16339, triggered by: 192.168.86.21)
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage (Time: 16340 ms, heap: 41704 bytes, from 192.168.86.112(5353), to 224.0.0.251(5353))
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage: Done (Succeeded after 4 ms, ate 0 bytes, remaining 41704)

[MDNSResponder] _callProcess (16352, triggered by: 192.168.86.112)
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage (Time: 16358 ms, heap: 41704 bytes, from 192.168.86.119(5353), to 224.0.0.251(5353))
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage: Done (Succeeded after 10 ms, ate 0 bytes, remaining 41704)

[MDNSResponder] _callProcess (16376, triggered by: 192.168.86.119)
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage (Time: 16381 ms, heap: 41672 bytes, from 192.168.86.127(5353), to 224.0.0.251(5353))
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage: Done (Succeeded after 10 ms, ate 0 bytes, remaining 41672)

[MDNSResponder] _callProcess (16399, triggered by: 192.168.86.127)
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage (Time: 16405 ms, heap: 41688 bytes, from 192.168.86.112(5353), to 224.0.0.251(5353))
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage: Done (Succeeded after 10 ms, ate 0 bytes, remaining 41688)

[MDNSResponder] _announce: Announcing host therm1 (content 0x3)
[MDNSResponder] _sendMDNSMessage_Multicast: Will send to '224.0.0.251'.
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage: ID:0 QR:1 OP:0 AA:1 TC:0 RD:0 RA:0 R:0 QD:0 AN:2 NS:0 AR:0
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_A (192.168.86.71)
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_PTR_IP4 (192.168.86.71)
[MDNSResponder] _updateProbeStatus: Announcing host (7).

[MDNSResponder] _announceService: Announcing service therm1.http.TCP (content 0xF0)
[MDNSResponder] _sendMDNSMessage_Multicast: Will send to '224.0.0.251'.
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage: ID:0 QR:1 OP:0 AA:1 TC:0 RD:0 RA:0 R:0 QD:0 AN:4 NS:0 AR:1
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_PTR_TYPE
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_PTR_NAME
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_SRV
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_TXT
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_A (192.168.86.71)
[MDNSResponder] _updateProbeStatus: Announcing service therm1.http.TCP (7)

[MDNSResponder] _callProcess (17221, triggered by: 192.168.86.112)
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage (Time: 17222 ms, heap: 41496 bytes, from 192.168.86.165(5353), to 224.0.0.251(5353))
[MDNSResponder] _readRRQuestion
[MDNSResponder] _readRRQuestion _googlecast._tcp.local Type:0x000C Class:0x0001 Multicast
[MDNSResponder] _readRRQuestion
[MDNSResponder] _readRRQuestion _233637DE._sub._googlecast._tcp.local Type:0x000C Class:0x0001 Multicast
[MDNSResponder] _parseQuery: No reply needed
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage: Done (Succeeded after 31 ms, ate 0 bytes, remaining 41496)

[MDNSResponder] _callProcess (17263, triggered by: 192.168.86.165)
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage (Time: 17266 ms, heap: 41200 bytes, from 192.168.86.21(5353), to 224.0.0.251(5353))
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage: Done (Succeeded after 10 ms, ate 0 bytes, remaining 41200)

[MDNSResponder] _callProcess (17428, triggered by: 192.168.86.21)
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage (Time: 17429 ms, heap: 41200 bytes, from 192.168.86.119(5353), to 224.0.0.251(5353))
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage: Done (Succeeded after 4 ms, ate 0 bytes, remaining 41200)

[MDNSResponder] _callProcess (17450, triggered by: 192.168.86.119)
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage (Time: 17451 ms, heap: 41184 bytes, from 192.168.86.119(5353), to 224.0.0.251(5353))
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage: Done (Succeeded after 6 ms, ate 0 bytes, remaining 41184)

[MDNSResponder] _callProcess (17465, triggered by: 192.168.86.119)
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage (Time: 17471 ms, heap: 41200 bytes, from 192.168.86.112(5353), to 224.0.0.251(5353))
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage: Done (Succeeded after 10 ms, ate 0 bytes, remaining 41200)

[MDNSResponder] _callProcess (17489, triggered by: 192.168.86.112)
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage (Time: 17494 ms, heap: 41160 bytes, from 192.168.86.112(5353), to 224.0.0.251(5353))
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage: Done (Succeeded after 10 ms, ate 0 bytes, remaining 41160)

[MDNSResponder] _callProcess (17512, triggered by: 192.168.86.112)
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage (Time: 17518 ms, heap: 41192 bytes, from 192.168.86.127(5353), to 224.0.0.251(5353))
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage: Done (Succeeded after 10 ms, ate 0 bytes, remaining 41192)

[MDNSResponder] _announce: Announcing host therm1 (content 0x3)
[MDNSResponder] _sendMDNSMessage_Multicast: Will send to '224.0.0.251'.
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage: ID:0 QR:1 OP:0 AA:1 TC:0 RD:0 RA:0 R:0 QD:0 AN:2 NS:0 AR:0
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_A (192.168.86.71)
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_PTR_IP4 (192.168.86.71)
[MDNSResponder] _updateProbeStatus: Done host announcing.

[MDNSResponder] _announceService: Announcing service therm1.http.TCP (content 0xF0)
[MDNSResponder] _sendMDNSMessage_Multicast: Will send to '224.0.0.251'.
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage: ID:0 QR:1 OP:0 AA:1 TC:0 RD:0 RA:0 R:0 QD:0 AN:4 NS:0 AR:1
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_PTR_TYPE
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_PTR_NAME
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_SRV
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_TXT
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_A (192.168.86.71)
[MDNSResponder] _updateProbeStatus: Done service announcing for therm1.http.TCP
```

And here it is responding to a query when I ping it from win10 client:

```
[MDNSResponder] _callProcess (141349, triggered by: 192.168.86.112)
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage (Time: 141351 ms, heap: 41184 bytes, from 192.168.86.112(5353), to 224.0.0.251(5353))
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage: Done (Succeeded after 11 ms, ate 0 bytes, remaining 41184)

[MDNSResponder] _callProcess (141381, triggered by: 192.168.86.112)
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage (Time: 141382 ms, heap: 41192 bytes, from 192.168.86.127(5353), to 224.0.0.251(5353))
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage: Done (Succeeded after 5 ms, ate 0 bytes, remaining 41192)

[MDNSResponder] _callProcess (156603, triggered by: 192.168.86.127)
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage (Time: 156604 ms, heap: 41528 bytes, from 192.168.86.27(5353), to 224.0.0.251(5353))
[MDNSResponder] _readRRQuestion
[MDNSResponder] _readRRQuestion therm1.local Type:0x0001 Class:0x0001 Multicast
[MDNSResponder] _replyMaskForHost: 0x1
[MDNSResponder] _parseQuery: Host reply needed 0x1
[MDNSResponder] _parseQuery: Sending answer(0x1)...
[MDNSResponder] _sendMDNSMessage_Multicast: Will send to '224.0.0.251'.
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage: ID:0 QR:1 OP:0 AA:1 TC:0 RD:0 RA:0 R:0 QD:0 AN:1 NS:0 AR:0
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_A (192.168.86.71)
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage: Done (Succeeded after 50 ms, ate 152 bytes, remaining 41376)

[MDNSResponder] _callProcess (157763, triggered by: 192.168.86.27)
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage (Time: 157764 ms, heap: 41528 bytes, from 192.168.86.27(5353), to 224.0.0.251(5353))
[MDNSResponder] _readRRQuestion
[MDNSResponder] _readRRQuestion therm1.local Type:0x0001 Class:0x0001 Multicast
[MDNSResponder] _replyMaskForHost: 0x1
[MDNSResponder] _parseQuery: Host reply needed 0x1
[MDNSResponder] _parseQuery: Sending answer(0x1)...
[MDNSResponder] _sendMDNSMessage_Multicast: Will send to '224.0.0.251'.
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage
[MDNSResponder] _prepareMDNSMessage: ID:0 QR:1 OP:0 AA:1 TC:0 RD:0 RA:0 R:0 QD:0 AN:1 NS:0 AR:0
[MDNSResponder] _writeMDNSAnswer_A (192.168.86.71)
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage: Done (Succeeded after 49 ms, ate 152 bytes, remaining 41376)

[MDNSResponder] _callProcess (157822, triggered by: 192.168.86.27)
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage (Time: 157827 ms, heap: 41352 bytes, from 192.168.86.27(5353), to 224.0.0.251(5353))
[MDNSResponder] _readRRQuestion
[MDNSResponder] _readRRQuestion therm1.local Type:0x001C Class:0x0001 Multicast
[MDNSResponder] _parseQuery: No reply needed
[MDNSResponder] _parseMessage: Done (Succeeded after 23 ms, ate 0 bytes, remaining 41352)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Picking this up two days later, it started working...nothing changed (in the code at least).